# Hacer una animación con css que al darle click al modal aparezca de izquierda a derecha

Tags: css

El código lo pongo en los comentarios; es un modal que se abre al apretar un botón, necesito darle una transición de derecha a izquierda cuando se abra y cuando se cierra de derecha a izquierda.

```
       .modalSecundario{
            margin-left: 40px;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 9999;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            display: none;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center; 
            
        }

        .fadee{
            transition: opacity .15s linear;
        }

        .modalSecundario.show{
            display: flex;
            // flex-direction: column;
        }

        .modalSecundario-container{
            position: relative;
            padding: 2rem;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow-y: auto;
            background-color: #fff;  
            //inicializo la transición
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
            -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
            &.fadee {
                .modalSecundario-container {
                    //creamos la transición
                    right: -320px;
                    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
                    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
                    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
                    transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
                }
                &.show {
                    .modalSecundario-container{
                        right: 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        .modalSecundario-close{
            position: absolute;
            top: 22px;
            left: 3.3rem; //izquierda
            background-color: transparent;
            border: none;
        }
        .ARROWLEFT path {
            fill: #001E50;
        }
        .spanBoton{
            color: #000000;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family:'VWText-Regular';
            margin-left: 8px;
        }
```

```
<article className={`modalSecundario fadee ${isOpen ?'show':''}`} onClick={closeModal}>
     <div className={`modalSecundario-container fadee`} onClick={handleModalContainerClick}>
        <button className='modalSecundario-close' onClick={closeModal}>
             <ARROWLEFT />
              <span className='text-center spanBoton'>
                  Atrás
              </span>
        </button>
        <div className='children mt-5'>
            {children}
        </div>
      </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Falta ejemplo para ver el funcionamiento. Pero según la función que quieres, el modal debe tener `left: -` por ejemplo 100px menos. Y cuando está visible o en `show` debe tener ` left: 0`

Comment: añado un ejemplo, https://www.vw.com.mx/es.html exactamente es ese, cuando le das click a icono de hambuerguesa, se te abre un "modal" que incluye links, y si le das click a un link se te abre otro modal y esa es la animación que quiero, del 2do "modal"